# Replace specific XML tag content in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have my xml file named Test.xml. I want to replace only the content of xml tag `<con:selectedAuthProfile>value</con:selectedAuthProfile>`from value to "Pharmacy-Authorization" inside the xml tag`<con:testStep>`with the id="123456789". I hope I could find code for this. Thankyou in advance guys! I'll explain the process below.

1. Search xml tag `<con:testStep type=a id=>` with id="123456789"
2. Inside that tag I need to replace the content of xml tag`<con:selectedAuthProfile>*</con:selectedAuthProfile>`

   Below is the code:

   ```
   <con:testStep type="a" name="TestStep 1" id="123456789">
      <xml1>XMLVALUE1</xml1>
      <xml2>XMLVALUE2</xml2>   
      <con:selectedAuthProfile>value</con:selectedAuthProfile>
   </con:testStep>
   <con:testStep type="b" name="TestStep 2" id="987654321">
      <xml3>XMLVALUE3</xml3>
      <xml4>XMLVALUE4</xml4>
      <con:selectedAuthProfile>value</con:selectedAuthProfile>
   </con:testStep>
   ```

As you can see in the XML there two Instances/Occurrence of the tag `<con:selectedAuthProfile>value</con:selectedAuthProfile>`. I only want to change the content of this tag based on its PARENT TAG which is `<con:testStep>` with an id="123456789". i hope it would be possible

Comment: its going to be tricky because `*` is reserved as a wildcard in batch.

Comment: I just put * as an example content. I'll just edit it :)

Comment: Ok I have a solution for changing specific words in a file I hope it helps

Comment: It would help. thankyou very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far, what particular part do you have problems with? Please share your efforts!

Comment: I have 2 kinds of code but it doesn't help. 1st one is to search for specific string and replace that line with some replace string. 2nd is search for string and replace only that string with replace string.

My problem is I only want to change specific Instance/Occurrence of a string with. In my XML file as you can see there are 2 instances of tag <con:selectedAuthProfile></con:selectedAuthProfile>. I only want to change the content of this tag based on its parent tag <con:testStep>

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of changing any particular word in a file.

You have to run two .bat scripts.
Name the scripts `Script1.bat` and `Script2.bat`.

`Script1`

```
@ECHO OFF
Script2.bat "Orange" "Apple" "file.txt" >"newfile.txt"
```

`Script2`

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Copy these two scripts into .txt files and rename them to .bat, also make sure you put them in the same folder as the file you want to edit.

The program replaces the word `Orange` with the word `Apple`. You only need to run Replace.bat

Your input file is located in `Script1` so edit that to suit your needs.